Is it possible to make an animation effect with this only image using CSS?
I would like to use this image of "Pikachu" running, without having to create a gif (as it is heavier), and I would like to use this effect of him running in css. How would I use this code? Can you help me?
image: https://game.gtimg.cn/images/nishiki/web202310/pkq_ani.png


.pikaqiu_run {
    width: 80px;
    height: 71px;
    background: url(//game.gtimg.cn/images/nishiki/web202310/pkq_ani.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    animation: steps(8, end) 0.5s infinite;
    right: 0;
    top: -71px;
}
<span class="pikaqiu_run"></span>






.center-container {
  height: 100vh;
  /* Use the full viewport height */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  /* Optional: changes the background color */
}

.pikaqiu_run {
  width: 80px;
  /* Width of one frame */
  height: 71px;
  /* Height of the frame */
  background: url('https://game.gtimg.cn/images/nishiki/web202310/pkq_ani.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
  animation: run-animation 0.5s steps(8, end) infinite;
}

@keyframes run-animation {
  from {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  to {
    background-position: -640px 0;
  }
  /* Adjust based on total width of all frames */
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<body>
  <div class="center-container">
    <div class="pikaqiu_run"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>



Applies the animation defined by @keyframes. It lasts for 0.5 seconds goes through 8 steps (assuming your sprite has 8 frames in a single row), and loops indefinitely.
@keyframes run-animation Defines how the background position shifts from the first frame to the last The -640px should be adjusted based on the total width of all frames in your sprite sheet (in this example, it's assumed that each frame is 80px wide and there are 8 frames, thus 80px × 8 = 640px).

Thank u so muchhhhh! It worked and was perfect! ♥
